# How can I modify code to work with a different HTML table format?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to use some javascript that will colour in red any dates in a row of a HTML table that have thirty days or less to run. The following example works fine, but I need to use the javascript code on a wordpress site using a plugin called tablepress, which uses a different table layout.

Can anybody please help me to modify the javascript code to work with the tablepress layout? Many thanks.

HTML Format that does work:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Face Cream</td><td>23-05-2015</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Aspirin</td><td>05-10-2015</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Arnica Cream</td><td>23-04-2015</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Vitamin C</td><td>06-04-2015</td></tr>
</table>
```

HTML Format that does not work:

```
 <table id="tablepress-2" class="tablepress tablepress-id-2">
    <thead>
    <tr class="row-1 odd">
    <th class="column-1">Item</th><th class="column-2">Expiry Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="row-hover">
    <tr class="row-2 even">
    <td class="column-1">Face Cream</td><td class="column-2">23/05/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-3 odd">
    <td class="column-1">Aspirin</td><td class="column-2">5/10/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-4 even">
    <td class="column-1">Arnica Cream</td><td class="column-2">23/04/2015</td>
   </tr>
    <tr class="row-5 odd">
    <td class="column-1">Vitamin C</td><td class="column-2">6/04/2015</td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

javascript expiry date colouring code:

```
function colorDate(){
var parents = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
var parent = parents[i],
    children = parent.children

for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
    var elem = children[j]
    if (j % 3 === 2) {
        var dateElement = elem.innerHTML;
        var dateArray = dateElement.split("-");     
        var prevTime = new Date( dateArray[2],dateArray[1]-1,dateArray[0]);
        var thisTime = new Date();
        var diff = prevTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();
        var days = 1000*60*60*24;
        var diffInDays = Math.ceil(diff / days);
        if (diffInDays > 30) {
            elem.style.color = "#008000";
        }

        else if (diffInDays <= 30) {
            elem.style.color = "#ff0000";
        }
        if(dateElement=="00-00-0000"){
            elem.style.color = "#0000ffr";
        }
     }
   }
}
}
colorDate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can get it much simpler, since all date cells have class. So:

```
function colorDate(){
var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".column-2");

    for(i=1;i<cells.length;i++){
        elem=cells[i];
        console.log(elem.innerHTML);
        var dateElement = elem.innerHTML;
        var dateArray = dateElement.split("/");     
        var prevTime = new Date( dateArray[2],dateArray[1]-1,dateArray[0]);
        var thisTime = new Date();
        var diff = prevTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();
        var days = 1000*60*60*24;
        var diffInDays = Math.ceil(diff / days);
        if (diffInDays > 30) {
            elem.style.color = "#008000";
        }

        else if (diffInDays <= 30) {
            elem.style.color = "#ff0000";
        }
        if(dateElement=="00-00-0000"){
            elem.style.color = "#0000ffr";
        }  
    }

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dc12drch/

Note: i have changed separator, for dateArray (for splitting). Note2: loop starts from 1, not zero, because we want to skip first cell (in table head).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your solution it works perfectly, but for some reason wordpress is not picking up/running the script.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your solution, it works perfectly, but for some reason wordpress is not picking up/running the script. Is it possible that the script needs to include the get element by id or class in order for it to be run on the wordpress page? If so how do you know how to point the script to the id of the table? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, update querySelector, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dc12drch/13/, and try to place code at the bottom of the page -> add it to footer template, maybe (That way you will be sure that DOM is loaded and that elements are present)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I have spent a long time looking for a solution to resolve this issue. Everything is working correctly now thanks to your input.